# xsl:for-each not returning any values

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML file containing multiple nodes (node6/total) into a CSV output file, but the for-each within the XSL fails to return anything on the output.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<File xmlns='urn:uk.co.visitors.v1'>
<Reference>175008-00123</Reference>
<Description>XTR22_2019-01-21</Description>
<Created>2019-01-21T13:45:46</Created>
<node1>
    <node2>
        <ref>REFERENCE</ref>
        <num>12345</num>
        <node3>
            <node4>
                <ref1>012345</ref1>
                <name>scarface</name>
                <location>1876 main street</location>
                <date>2019-01-21</date>
                <ref2>012345</ref2>
                <cost>0.00</cost>
                <paid>9.99</paid>
                <node5>
                    <node6>
                        <detail>check-in</detail>
                        <ondate>2019-01-21</ondate>
                        <time>08:00:00</time>
                        <total>40</total>
                        <update>FALSE</update>
                    </node6>
                    <node6>
                        <detail>check-in</detail>
                        <ondate>2019-01-22</ondate>
                        <time>23:00:00</time>
                        <total>10</total>
                        <update>TRUE</update>
                    </node6>
                    <node6>
                        <detail>check-out</detail>
                        <ondate>2019-01-25</ondate>
                        <time>11:00:00</time>
                        <total>5</total>
                        <update>TRUE</update>
                    </node6>
                </node5>
            </node4>
        </node3>
    </node2>
</node1>
</File>
```

XSL Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'&#59;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>column1;column2;total</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        <xsl:text>X45</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
        <xsl:text>NONE</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />

        <xsl:for-each select="/File/node1/node2/node3/node4/node5/node6/total">
            <xsl:value-of select="total" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried updating the value of the for-each select to match various paths to the required node, to no avail.

The expected result is a CSV file containing 3 headers and 3 lines of data:

```
column1;column2;total;
X45;NONE;40;
X45;NONE;10;
X45;NONE;5;
```

The current output is as follows:

```
column1;column2;total;
X45;NONE;
```

The file I am working with is substantially larger but this is a sample based on the above code.

Would appreciate any assistance or advice as to how to achieve this.

Comment: Your XML is in a *namespace* - look it up. -- Note also that `<xsl:value-of select="total" />` selects nothing when you're already in the context of `total`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the namespace to my XSL `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:ns1="urn:uk.co.visitors.v1">` and updated to: `<xsl:for-each select="/File/node1/node2/node3/node4/node5/node6/">` for the total, but still nothing is returned. is it still something to do with the namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, the elements are in a namespace. One approach is using the namespace prefix `ns1` on all XPath expressions. Then your `for-each` XPath would look like this:

```
/ns1:File/ns1:node1/ns1:node2/ns1:node3/ns1:node4/ns1:node5/ns1:node6
```

And you have to use it on the `ns1:total` as well.

The other way is setting the `xpath-default-namespace="urn:uk.co.visitors.v1"` attribute of the `xsl:stylesheet` element. Then you can leave your code as is (Like in the code below).

Two other things: aside from removing the `total` from the `for-each` expression, you have to move the `X45` and `NONE` texts into the `for-each` loop.

Combining all this, your template could be simplified to this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>column1;column2;total</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/File/node1/node2/node3/node4/node5/node6">
        <xsl:text>X45</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
        <xsl:text>NONE</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
        <xsl:value-of select="total" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($delimiter,$newline)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives you the desired output. It can be further simplified to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>column1;column2;total</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/File/node1/node2/node3/node4/node5/node6">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('X45',$delimiter,'NONE',$delimiter,total,$delimiter,$newline)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much @zx485! One final question, if I then want to access something in <node2>, for example <ref>  and add this as a 4th column, can I just add it as `<xsl:value-of select="/File/node1/node2/total" />` ?

Comment: That depends on the whole situation. It would probably be best to go back from the current node: `../../../../ref` would go back from the current `node6` to `node2` and then select the `ref` element. But if you have only one `node2` element, you can use your approach: `/File/node1/node2/ref`.

Comment: Instead of constantly walking up and down the tree, do `<xsl:for-each select="/File/node1/node2">` and store the value of `ref` in a variable. Then continue with `<xsl:for-each select="node3/node4/node5/node6">`.

Comment: P.S. I cannot see the purpose of using `concat() ` when writing to the output.